# How to control a customized UITableViewCell within a UITableView Implemented within a UIViewController?

Tags: ios5, uitableview, custom-controls

In my app I wish to have a **UIViewController** that will hold a **UITableView** in it. In this UITableView I wish to have a **customized UITableViewCell** (i.e. I wish to define my own elements in this CELL - image, labels and buttons - as seen in the image below). And... I want to create them in the Storyboard.

- Now, setting the elements in the Storyboard is easy.
- I understand how to connect the UITableView and set it in the UIViewController (including the delegates in the .h file and using the basic table delegate methods).
- What I'm not clear about, is how to connect and control the customized UITableViewCell and its outlets. Can I create the Outlets and Actions within the **UIViewController** .h and .m files? Do I need to create a separated **UITableViewCell.h/.m** files and call on them in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Can anyone suggest what's the best approach for my needs?

[image]

**UPDATE**: 
Here is the code I used in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** while using the separated **MyCell.h/m** file option. This code is written in the **ViewController.m** file, where the UITableView is implemented.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ContentCell";

    MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

//MyCell is the Objective-C Class I created to manage the table cells attributes.

//@"ContentCell" is what I had entered in the Storyboard>>UITableViewCell as the Cell Identifier.

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
//Here is the place I'm not clear about - Am I supposed to init the cell in a different way? If so, how?    
    }

    cell.contentNameLabel.text = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];

// this is the test I had done to check if the new "MyCell" object is actually getting what I would expect it to get. well... the text gets updated in the relevant label, so i guess it gets it 

    return cell;

}
```

When running the app, using the debugger break point, I can see that the code always skips the "if (cell == nil)" and never enters the code where the new MyCell object supposes to be allocated and initiated. Any idea what may I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, create separate UITableViewCell.h/.m files to match your custom UITableViewCell class and call on them in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

In your storyboard, set the class of your custom UITableViewCell to your custom class (e.g. CustomTableCell).

Your custom UITableViewCell class would contain IBOutlets which you would wire up in your storyboard, here is an example:

CustomTableCell.h:

```
#import "CustomStuff.h" // A custom data class, for this example

@interface CustomTableCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;

- (void)configureForCustomStuff:(CustomStuff *)stuff;

@end
```

CustomTableCell.m:

```
#import "CustomTableCell.h"

@implementation CustomTableCell

@synthesize titleLabel;

#pragma mark - Configure the table view cell

- (void)configureForCustomStuff:(CustomStuff *)stuff
{
    // Set your outlets here, e.g.
    self.titleLabel.text = stuff.title;
}

@end
```

Then, in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, configure your cell:

```
CustomTableCell *cell = (CustomTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCellID"];

// Your custom data here
CustomStuff *customStuff = <YOUR CUSTOM STUFF>

[cell configureForCustomStuff:customStuff];
```

Comment: thank you Marco for the detailed answer. Still, something is not working right when I implement it; Maybe you'll have some idea about it. I'm able to create the table and fill the cells labels with my data (I take from this that the cells are created properly); but the didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not working. When I test it and click on a certain row the app crashes; I have a break point within didSelectRowAtIndexPath and the app never gets there.

Comment: Did you set your table view cell identifier in the storyboard, and does it match in cellForRowAtIndexPath:?

Comment: Hi Marco, I added to my original question the way I implemented cellForRowAtIndexPath. I think I did something wrong there, but I'm not totally sure. Can you take a look at it?